# angular4 ng-class on body, on different routes

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

I am applying condition based class on body tag , when we on login, then abc class will be apply on login, otherwise simple default body tag will be apply.

```
<body *ngIf="router.url === '/login': 'class.my-class'">
```

But its not working. Can anyone tell me how can i do this with angular 2 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

This example expects that you already get the `url` in your component via `router.url`.

`ngIf` will not add `class` to the element. Instead you can use

```
<body [class.my-class]="router.url === '/login'" >
```

For more you can read [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets)

Comment: class is not implemented yet. kindly tell whats the issue

Comment: What do you mean saying `class is not implemented yet` ? Your syntax with ngIf will not add the class to the body. I have provided the correct syntax

Comment: bro i want to implement abc class on body tag, on /login url. i have applied your code. but class not implemented yet on login url